# Install macruby to specific directory?

Tags: ruby, macos, macruby

Normally macruby wants to install to /usr/local via 'rake install'

I want it in another location. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Running rake -T gives the options (duh, stupid me)

It tells me

```
rake install sym_instdir=/some/place
```

Is the trick to install to another directory and this does in fact work.

EDIT: I spoke too soon.

This makes the symlinks, but there is the framework_instdir option as well, but changing that doesn't seem to make any difference...

Answer (score 1):

```
$ DESTDIR = /some/place rake install
```

Look at the nightly built rake task for a more concrete example.

- Matt